# Azure sql database subscription

Tags: database, azure, subscription

I have a project for university and i have to use Azure Sql Database. I've made a student account which gave me 100 dollars to spend.
My problem is that in 2 or 3 days all my money were gone and now my subscription is disabled. I will make another account or something, but my question is: do you know why it cost me that much?

[image]

I think i've done something wrong when creating the database, because i don't think it costs that much usually. Can you help me understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a complement:

Please go to Azure SQL database configure page to check the current price tier of the database:

[image]

If your database is not very large(less than 2G), you could change to DTU based model price tier, you only need to pay for 4.99$/month.

Ref: [Service tiers in the DTU-based purchase model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tiers-dtu).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I've changed to DTU, that's what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

MSSQL in azure is not cheap.As I understand you created a plan with vCores that has a standard cost plus the cost for the data storage.

I would suggest you go with a DTUs plan that is much cheaper, and it would perform fine for university projects.